# Windows Form Combobox DropDown event causing dialog form to lose focus

Tags: c#, combobox, focus

I'm creating a settings form that is quite similar to the Visual Studio 2008 "Connect To Database" form in the Server Explorer.

The settings form is opened as a modal dialog from the parent form as follows:

```
    private void settingsToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var SettingsForm = new frmSettings();
        SettingsForm.ShowDialog(this); 
    }
```

On the SettingsForm, I have a ComboBox that will populate its list with the SQLServer instance names available on the network through the following code in the DropDown event:

```
    private void cboTrackingServerName_DropDown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dt = SmoApplication.EnumAvailableSqlServers(false);
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            cboTrackingServerName.Items.Clear();

            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                cboTrackingServerName.Items.Add(
                     row["Server"] + "\\" + row["Instance"]);
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem is that whenever the user clicks the DropDown arrow on the ComboBox, the SettingsForm loses focus to its parent form for a quick second, the SettingsForm appears to redraw itself, and then the SettingsForm regains focus.  This also causes the actual DropDown list not to appear until the user clicks it again.

Any helpful thoughts on the matter?

Comment: Could you just move the population of the combo box to the Form_Load of the dialog form?

Comment: @David McEwing: Yes, but I'd rather not.  Loading the DataTable from SmoApplication.EnumAvailableSqlServers has a bit of a delay on it, which causes the Form_Load to hang for a few seconds.  I'd rather have the delay isolated to when the user want's to actually change the value.

Comment: What about kicking off a background thread from Form_Load and populating the dialog on that.  Then Form_Load will complete quick, Doing it on the DropDown event is the wrong location.  In ASP.NET I would do it on the DataBound and just call the Bind() method from page_load.  Would that work in this situation?

Comment: I will try that out, David - thanks!

Comment: The backgroundWorder worked very well - Thank you @David McEwing and @bigtlb.  I put a while() loop checking a ServerNamesLoaded boolean on the _DropDown event of the combo box, so that if the user clicks on the dropdown arrow while the list is still loading, it gives them the wait timer. I tried the IsBusy method of the backgroundWorker object for this, but it was staying true, and I couldn't figure out how to make it false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably do this earlier in the dialog life cycle, like Form_Load.  Also, even if you needed to do it here, don't keep reloading the list.  Check to see if the list is already loaded.  Otherwise you will wipe out the current selection everytime the user opens the dropdown.

Comment: Thanks, I have the list-checks and SelectedItem logic already in place, but they were irrelevant to the bug I'm having.  What I posted is the minimum marketable bug ;)  See the above comment to @David McEwing for my feelings about Form_Load in this instance.

Comment: Moving the work to a background or asynchronous thread is a good idea. You should not add the items to the dropdown from there though. That should be done from the UI threadBackgroundWorker was made just for this purpose. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx Have the worker do the call and return the list for the DropDown in the RunWorkerCompleted event.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the DropDown event for fetching Available Server Instances the best approach would be to use the `Form.Load`  Event.

But if for some reason you want to fill the list when user opens the drop down then the you should use **`ComboBox.Click`** Event.

In latter approach when you click on combo-box to open its dropdown, first the click event will be raised and then DropDown Event and hence no refreshing and lost of dropdown. However there will still be a little lag in clicking and opening of dropdown. For quick and perfect solution go with form load event.

Comment: The click event causes the same delay, unfortunately.  Form_Load combined with backgroundWorker solved the problem.